# How to run the akka grpc java example

Tags: java, gradle, akka, akka-grpc

Ok, following the prerequisites and instructions to use Java 8 the project creation works.

`sbt new akka/akka-grpc-quickstart-java.g8`

Then continuing with the [guide](https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-grpc-quickstart-java/)

`./gradlew compileJava` works as well.

but then `./gradlew --info runServer` fails with the folling errors/issues:

```
Task ':runServer' is not up-to-date because:
Task has not declared any outputs.
```

and

```
Error: Main method not found in class com.example.helloworld.GreeterServer, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

***ORIGINAL POST:***

I am having trouble getting the Akka-GRPC example to run.
I tried following [this guide here](https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-grpc-quickstart-java/) but when I download the sample project it seems incomplete.

Thats the tree command output:

```
.
├── build.sbt
├── project
│   ├── build.properties
│   └── plugins.sbt
├── sbt
├── sbt.bat
└── sbt-dist
    ├── bin
    │   ├── sbt
    │   ├── sbt.bat
    │   ├── sbt-launch.jar
    │   └── sbt-launch-lib.bash
    └── conf
        ├── sbtconfig.txt
        └── sbtopts

4 directories, 11 files
```

There are no source files or gradlew oder pom.xml in the project structure.

Next I cloned the [repository of that example from GitHub](https://github.com/akka/akka-grpc-quickstart-java.g8) and followed the instructions in readme, mainly the command `sbt new akka/akka-grpc-quickstart-java.g8`.

```
$ sbt new akka/akka-grpc-quickstart-java.g8
[info] Loading settings for project akka-grpc-quickstart-java-g8-build from paradox.sbt,giter8.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/johannes/IdeaProjects/akka-grpc-quickstart-java.g8/project
error: error while loading String, class file '/modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class' is broken
(class java.lang.NullPointerException/null)
[error] java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI
...//had to remove stacktrace was too long for this post
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? [error] java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

then I went into the project/sources folder ./src/main/g8/ where the source files are located and tried to follow the instructions from the guide from in there.
That also did not work because of some properties errors:

Before that I had to set another gradle version (6.1.1, was 4.5.1) in ./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to make it compatible with Java 13.

```
$ ./gradlew compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'g8'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle.plugin.com.lightbend.akka.grpc:akka-grpc-gradle-plugin:$akka_grpc_version$.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/home/johannes/.m2/repository/gradle/plugin/com/lightbend/akka/grpc/akka-grpc-gradle-plugin/$akka_grpc_version$/akka-grpc-gradle-plugin-$akka_grpc_version$.pom
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/com/lightbend/akka/grpc/akka-grpc-gradle-plugin/$akka_grpc_version$/akka-grpc-gradle-plugin-$akka_grpc_version$.pom
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
```

Trying to at least temporarily get this to work i hardcoded the properties into the build.gradle file:

```
     //classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.lightbend.akka.grpc:akka-grpc-gradle-plugin:$akka_grpc_version$'
     classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.lightbend.akka.grpc:akka-grpc-gradle-plugin:0.7.3'
```

But that also only got me so far:

```
$ ./gradlew compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/johannes/IdeaProjects/akka-grpc-quickstart-java.g8/src/main/g8/build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'g8'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.google.protobuf']
   > Could not create an instance of type com.google.protobuf.gradle.ProtobufSourceDirectorySet.
      > 'void org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.gradle.api.internal.file.FileResolver, org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTreeFactory)'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Again could not include whole stacktrace because of character limit.

What am I missing?
Which approach should I pursue further?

Comment: Seems to be a version mismatch between the plugin and the gradle API. The latest version of the plugin seems to be this really awkward version string you can find here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/gradle.plugin.com.lightbend.akka.grpc/akka-grpc-gradle-plugin/0.7.3+51-01190fed , maybe give that a try.

Comment: where do I configure this? in build.gradle? or in gradle-wrapper.properties?

Comment: ... you yourself posted the plugin configuration which you state is in build.gradle right there in the question. I am not fully expecting this to work, I can only say that errors indicating that method parameters do not match up tend to indicate that you have version conflicts between libraries which in this case would be a plugin which is not built for the version of gradle you are using.

Comment: ouch, sorry about this bumpy ride, I'll look into fixing some of those things.

Comment: A good way to get started might be to run 'sbt new akka/akka-grpc-quickstart-java.g8' in a directory *without* first checking out the source code

Comment: using java 8 i got through the 'sbt new ... ' command (with a minor hickup).  I am still stuck at ./gradlew runServer (some gradle error again).
I will update the post when I get back to my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Meanwhile, the pull request was accepted and the main repo (https://github.com/akka/akka-grpc-quickstart-java.g8) is up-to-date.

I downloaded the project using sbt new ..., but there was an error within the pom.xml (fixed version: https://github.com/olitazl/akka-grpc-quickstart-java.g8)

The problem of the example project are missing `public` modifier inside the `GreeterServer` class.

Therefore, you have to add `public` to the GreeterServer class and the method `main` within.

```
    public class GreeterServer ...
    public static void main(...)
```

If you recreate your project from my repo, the problem is fixed there as well.